# Strange Swift 2 Bug, Crash when source code is in separate file

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

I have the following code.

**ViewController.Swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let someClass = Test()
        someClass.someProtocol.someMethod()
    }
}
```

**Code.Swift**

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var someInt: Int {get set}
    func someMethod()
}

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    var someInt: Int
    init() {
        someInt = Int()
    }
    func someMethod() {
        print("hello")
    }
}

class Test {
    let someProtocol: SomeProtocol
    init() {
        self.someProtocol = SomeClass()
    }
}
```

This code compiles completely fine on Xcode 6/Swift 1.2, but in Xcode 7/Swift 2 `someMethod` is never called, instead I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on `someInt`

However if I move the code from **Code.Swift** to the **ViewController.Swift** file (so that all the source code is in the same file) I don't get a crash.

Has anyone experienced this issue with Swift 2 or know why this is happening?
Thanks

**Update**: Even stranger, if I mark the SomeClass class as final, I don't get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash, but the method still never gets called.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Consider reporting it on bugreport.apple.com. There have been lots of issue with Swift since its creation (though most of them have been resolved), so it wouldn't be that surprising.

Comment: Are you moving that code in and out of a framework - because that would do it if you are using storyboards.  Start with the base condition, the one that works, and check the scoping in IB (does it say MyFramwork.ViewController?).  Then move the code, and double check the connection - does it still autocomplete, or does it not find it?  In my experience, IB does not complain if it cannot resolve the backing class, only if it finds the class but not the method.

Comment: @zneak I have reported it on both radar and the developer forums.

Comment: @chrisco Nope, and I'm positive this has nothing to do with IB. It seems the compiler is generating bad code when having an instance that has a reference to a object that inherits a property from a protocol in a separate file. Yes a very specific case but it's really not that uncommon to have the scenario I posted above. Essentially I'm just using the protocol as an abstract class. This crashes when compiled for OS X as well. But as long as all of the source code is in the same file no crash.

Comment: To be complete, I did have a problem like this pre 1.0 - might have been a compiler crash when code was in separate files.  It's hard to imagine how the compiler could be so complex, but this won't be the strangest bug that you file.

Answer (score 0):

it works as expected, at least for me. I checked it on both XCode 7.2.1  and last 7.3 beta resp.